# How to Mask IP addresses and Force HTTPS with Google Global Site Tag gtag.js?

Tags: google-analytics, privacy, gtag.js

How to Mask IP addresses and Force HTTPS with Google Global Site Tag gtag.js ?

In the old tracking code this is done with:

```
ga('set', 'forceSSL', true) //force https
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true) //mask ip last digits
```

Is this done like below in the new tracking code with gtag with { 'anonymize_ip': true }, { 'forceSSL': true} ?

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', { 'anonymize_ip': true }, { 'forceSSL': true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the pageview parameters as a JSON object:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', { 'anonymize_ip': true, 'forceSSL': true });
```

See the [Track Pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages) documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Joep-Grooten - I guess this answers the question then.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way closer to the analytics.js syntax and that ensures that every subsequent hits are using the same options.

You use the 'set' command before any call that fires a hit.

'set' takes an object with pairs of parameters names using lower case and '_' bewteen words instead of camelCase in analytics.js

```
gtag('set', { 'anonymize_ip': true, 'force_ssl': true });
gtag('config', 'UA-999999999999-99' );
```

See the feedback in debug mode [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXpDn.png) to validate your syntax and check that is it taken into account.
You can activate the debug mode with the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) Chrome extension